# How to use $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] with Phpunit

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I am trying to set up Phpunit and across my whole project, `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is used to link all files/functions/the connection etc. In my test class if I link the absolute path of my `global_php_includes.php` file (which is the parent file that contains more includes for everything else) then it gets an error every time $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] is called.

I'm very new to Phpunit, is there any way to solve this? I installed it using composer. Here is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<phpunit bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php" colors="true" verbose="true" stopOnFailure="true">

    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="unit">
            <directory>tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

</phpunit>
```

Comment: which error you get?

Comment: Everything an include using Document_Root is mentioned I get an error that there is `No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0):

Facing this issue, you can't do it (as far as I know).

If you launch **phpunit** through CLI, it's not use by the server directly, but with PHP, so you have to specify the absolute path (the same way that if you do a cron job).

I recommend you to use **classes** with you website to make it easier to use PHPUnit, but use absolute path for you project